# Why is my infrared receiver working on my Beaglebone Black but not my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, infrared, remote-control, beaglebone-black

I have a [TSOP4438](https://www.vishay.com/docs/82459/tsop48.pdf) wired to GPIO pins of a Raspberry Pi Zero W and Beaglebone Black as shown in the diagram:

[image: Wiring diagram]

I'm trying to use this to control my Pi with an old Roku remote. I initially tried this setup with only the Pi, but after experiencing the issues described below I hooked up the BBB for debugging purposes. Both the Pi and BBB are powered via a laptop USB port.

Both the Pi and BBB are running this Python script (except the BBB uses Adafruit_BBB.GPIO instead of RPi.GPIO and a different pin name). Essentially, it just decodes the IR pulses to a hex value, tries to determine which button was pressed based on what the value is, and displays "Unknown: [value]" if the value doesn't correspond to a button:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import traceback
    
PinIn = 21
button_dict = {
    0x357e354ab: "ok",
    0x357e36699: "back",
    0x357e3c03f: "home",
    0x357e3e817: "power",
    0x357e39867: "up",
    0x357e37887: "left",
    0x357e3b44b: "right",
    0x357e3cc33: "down",
    0x357e3f00f: "volume_up",
    0x357e308f7: "volume_down",
    0x357e304fb: "mute",
    0x357e31ee1: "arrow",
    0x357e346b9: "moon",
    0x357e38679: "star",
    0x357e32cd3: "rewind",
    0x357e332cd: "play/pause",
    0x357e3aa55: "fast_forward",
    0x357e34ab5: "netflix",
    0x357e330cf: "disney+",
    0x357e3b24d: "hulu",
    0x357e310ef: "vudu"
}

#Sets up GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
# GPIO.setup(PinIn, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(PinIn, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


        
def poll_sensor(): #Pulls data from sensor
    num1s = 0 #Number of consecutive 1s
    command = [] #Pulses and their timings
    binary = 0b1 #Decoded binary command
    previousValue = 0 #The previous pin state
    value = GPIO.input(PinIn) #Current pin state
    
    while value: #Waits until pin is pulled low
        value = GPIO.input(PinIn)
    
    startTime = time.time() #Sets start time
    
    while True:
        if value != previousValue: #Waits until change in state occurs
            now = time.time() #Records the current time
            pulseLength = (now - startTime) * 1000000 #Calculate time in between pulses in microseconds
            startTime = now #Resets the start time
            command.append((previousValue, pulseLength)) #Adds pulse time to array (previous val acts as an alternating 1 / 0 to show whether time is the on time or off time)
        
        #Interrupts code if an extended high period is detected (End Of Command)    
        if value:
            num1s += 1
        else:
            num1s = 0
        
        if num1s > 10000:
            break
        
        #Reads values again
        previousValue = value
        value = GPIO.input(PinIn)
        
    #Covers data to binary
    for (typ, tme) in command:
        if typ == 1:
            binary = binary << 1
            if tme > 1000: #According to NEC protocol a gap of 1687.5 microseconds repesents a logical 1 so over 1000 should make a big enough distinction
                binary += 1
                
    if binary.bit_length() > 34: #Sometimes the binary has two rouge charactes on the end
        binary = binary >> (binary.bit_length() - 34)
        
    return binary
    
#Main program loop
try:
    while True:
        command = poll_sensor()
        if command in button_dict:
            print(button_dict[command])
        elif command > 100:
            print("Unknown:", hex(command))
except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I run this code on both SBC's and press the "OK" button on the remote 10 times, this is the output I get from the BBB:

```
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
```

And this is the output I get from the Pi:

```
Unknown: 0x3abbabf1a
Unknown: 0x3ad5f8aaa
ok
Unknown: 0x357e6aabd
Unknown: 0x3abf1aa55
Unknown: 0x357e3a6bd
ok
Unknown: 0x257c752af
Unknown: 0x3abf1aa55
Unknown: 0x357e35b7a
```

So the BBB is decoding ~97% of the pulses correctly while the Pi decodes only 20% of them. Why is this happening? The wiring, code, and positioning of the remote/receiver are all the same. As far as I know, the only thing that's different is the type of SBC. Are the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins inherently worse? Or maybe there's some other kind of limitation that keeps it from sampling as well as the BBB?

Here are some things I've tried with no change in results:

1. Disabling the internal pullup resistor in the code
2. Using different GPIO pins on the Pi
3. Running pigpio gpiotest to see if any of the GPIOs on the Pi were fried (they weren't)
4. Powering the receiver using the BBB's 3V3 rail instead of the Pi's
5. Connecting a low pass RC filter (10kOhm/100pf) between the output of the receiver and the GPIO pins
6. Connecting BBB ground to Pi ground
7. Switching the TSOP4438 with a [TSOP38238](https://www.vishay.com/docs/82491/tsop382.pdf)
8. Powering the Pi from a 5V wall wort

Comment: what about `9. disconnect BBB`?

Comment: Sorry this wasn't made clear in my initial draft but I initially tried this with no BBB and I experienced the same issue, hence why I used the BBB for debugging in the first place. I did try disconnecting the BBB again but it didn't change my results.

Comment: Figured it out for anyone curious. I forgot I had created a systemd service on the Pi and not the BBB, and it was running and keeping the CPU busy. Once this service was disabled, the Pi was able to receive the remote signal with the same accuracy as the BBB.